# Not able to change path to a directory in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I need to change the directory to following path

```
/media/New Volume/softwr/pgm
```

and

```
/home/sdk
```

for 2 diff purpose.
But by using cd its not working

I tried

`cd media` and `cd home`

Both time its showing such file or directory not existing. I am new to Linux environment.I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS
Can anyone help?

Comment: Where and how did you create the directories?

Comment: Are you sure that those directories exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change directories in the terminal, and know which directory I'm in?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161313/how-do-i-change-directories-in-the-terminal-and-know-which-directory-im-in)

Comment: @Mitch  those where already existing.New volume is the D drive of windows which is also accessible from linux.2 os in system

Comment: @RaduRădeanu i already checked it.bt thats not working for me.

Comment: @Sjk If you are sure that `New Volume` exists in `/media`, you should use: `cd /media/New\ Volume` or `cd "/media/New Volume"` because of that space.

Comment: Just make sure, that both directories already exist, if not create them (in the case of `/home` be cautious)! Once that is done open a a Terminal-window and drag the folder in the path of choice into it, to see the actual path

Comment: @v2r directories already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a Terminal, the working directory is you home, so you can easily go to `/home/sdk` by entering:

```
cd sdk
```

Otherwise, you should type the complete address beginning with `/`. In the case of an address contains spaces you have to use quotations or use `\` before the space. Like:

```
cd "/media/New Volume/softwr/pgm"
```

or

```
cd /media/New\ Volume/softwr/pgm
```

Note that Linux is case-sensitive, so be careful about the uppercase letters.

Comment: .I didnt knew about this problem with space and case-sensitive issue.it works thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`cd media` and `cd home` will never work because you are trying to change to a directory called `media` or `home` in your current directory.

```
braiam@braiam-PX741AA-ABA-A1104X:~$ cd media
bash: cd: media: No such file or directory
braiam@braiam-PX741AA-ABA-A1104X:~$ cd home
bash: cd: home: No such file or directory
```

The correct path is with `/` at the start.

```
:~$ cd /media
:/media$ 
:~$ cd /home
:/home$
```

Read the Relative and Absolute path of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/277612/169736) for more information.