# Problem In Installing Netbeans IDE in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, netbeans

I am a newbie to the Linux Environment(Ubuntu in this case) and I needed to download Netbeans for developing a software i'm working on. So, I read it on the web about how to install Netbeans on Ubuntu. I have performed all the previous steps successfully , Now when I'm running this comand

```
chmod +x netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh
```

to make the '.sh' file executable, the terminal is showing this error

```
chmod: cannot access 'netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh': No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to Proceed now. Any and every help shall be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance !
PS: I've already downloaded the '`netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh`' file

Comment: You need to run that command while in the folder where it was downloaded (or copy/move it to the root of your user area where the terminal opens by default)

Comment: I doubt on your filename or path.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia can you please explain me how to do either of them , since i'm a newbie ,I am not familiar with the process

Comment: Assuming you downloaded the file to the Downloads folder, you'd first do `cd Downloads` then run the command. The prompt shows where you are at any moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change directories in the terminal, and know which directory I'm in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161313/how-do-i-change-directories-in-the-terminal-and-know-which-directory-im-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install netbeans from umake?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040049/how-to-install-netbeans-from-umake)

Answer (score 0):

The error `No such file or directory` occurs when the file/directory mentioned in the command given does not exist in the location.

Assuming you downloaded the file to the default `Downloads` folder then you need to go to that folder first:

```
cd Downloads
```

Then issue the command you want, `chmod +x netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh`